# Bash script regex match 1 or 2 digits

Tags: regex, bash

I am writing a Bash script to extract part numbers from filenames. The filenames are named: part-number-N.jpg or part-number-NN.jpg where "N" is a digit.

In this script, "$files" is just a list of files in a directory.

```
for f in $files; do 
  fileName=$(basename $f)
  tmp=${fileName%.jpg}
  partNo=${tmp%-[0-9]}
done
```

How do I update this script to remove a hyphen followed by up to two digits at the end of the string?

Comment: Many of the part numbers have hyphens as part of the number, so I do not want to remove everything after a hyphen (although everything after the last hyphen would do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [extended globs](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)

```
shopt -s extglob
partNo="${tmp%-[[:digit:]]?([[:digit:]])}"
```

Also, you'd be better served storing your files in an array ( `files=(file1 file2 "file with embedded spaces in name"..)` ) and looping over the array like this - `for file in "${files[@]}"`. Also double-quote variables liberally

Answer (score 0):

**Late Answer**

You can also use `sed` within your loop to manipulate the file names :

```
for f in $files/*; do
    newFile=$(basename $f | sed 's/-[0-9][0-9]*//')
    echo $newFile
done
```

**Output**

```
part-number-N.jpg  ->  part-number.jpg
part-number-NN.jpg ->  part-number.jpg
```

Comment: BTW, I'm a little confused, did you want to keep the extension? My code preserves it.